# export structure of xml file to avoid empty file when using bcp utility in SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I am using bcp command to export data in the form of xml file in SQL Server, but When there is no data to export a empty file is exported. I need help with this. Is there any way to export the structure of xml file in case there is no data, as sending the empty file creates a problem. 
If you need me to provide additional info, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling your BCP command (from SQL code, application, filesystem...)?

Comment: calling the BCP command from SQL code: 'bcp "SELECT * FROM ' +@SRC_FILE + ' FOR XML PATH ('''+@PATH+'''), ROOT ('''+@ROOT+''') " queryout "' +@DST_PATH+@DST_FILE+@DT+ '.XML" -w -r -T'